# Jenkins - how to test jobs/scripts/any other configuration modifications

Tags: jenkins, devops

As devOps engineer I am doing lot of modifications in jenkins jobs/scripts/other configurations.
I am trying to find a strategy to check my modifications.
The status now is that problems comes when users use the jobs.
I cant run All the jobs every time, and part of them affect production.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: The problem I have mostly encountered with Jenkins and pipelines is mostly that it has side-effects. Namely if the only goal of pipeline is to deploy something, then I have to either deploy it or mock the deployment to test it. And mocking a deployment usually means checking if proper command has been invoked, which kind of makes little sense. Good question though, I am quite interessted in the answers myself.

Comment: I found this option - https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit - Junit for pipelines. it can help. I have jobs that are not pipeline. so more ideas will help.